# Rag and Razz--slang for teasing/ridiculing--which came first and what's the etymology of the words?

Tags: etymology, slang

Hopefully everyone understands to razz and to rag as meaning to tease/ridicule on account of I don't have anything specific to reference. I'm curious to know which word came first and why both words--rag and razz--were chosen for teasing and ridiculing. I'm having difficulty uncovering their etymologies in regards to these meanings.

Comment: Rag could have come from rhyming with Nag.  Razz could well be short for giving someone Raspberries, i.e. "Phhft!"

Comment: Note that bag on X is *another* slang for ridiculing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From OED...

> **razz** slang (orig. and chiefly US). trans.
>    *To deride, jeer; to mock or make fun of (a person or thing).*

...for which the first citation is 1918. They list the noun form **razzing** (also derived from *raspberry = contemptuous blowing sound*) a year earlier in 1917.

> **rag** trans. slang. (etymology uncertain, perhaps from *rag = tear, rend, rip*)
>    *tease or torment; (originally University slang) to make fun of in a rough or boisterous manner*

Where the first citation for that exact sense is 1749, with the cognate BrE slang *rag = scold, reprove* a decade earlier.

---

Personally I've rarely encountered the above use of *razz*, perhaps because it's still essentially US slang. I'm more familiar with the (mainly BrE slang) usage...

> **on the razz** (from [razzle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/razzle))
>    *out having a good time, socializing, or drinking.*

---

TL;DR: For OP's specific sense, **rag** is much older than **razz**.